# Python internationalization, local setting independent

Tags: python, internationalization

I need the return of a strftime() call being in a language different at the one set on my local machine/OS.
Is that possible to choose the language of the return?

Answer (score 1):

For solid i18n/L10N, usable by a server which must serve different localizations within the same run, I keep recommending [PyICU](http://pyicu.osafoundation.org/), the Python layer on top of [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), the International Components for Unicode open-source package.  Other approaches tend to be pretty limited and fragile:-(.

Answer (score 0):

Try the babel library: http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/dates.html